# Is there a Python caching library?

Tags: python, caching

I'm looking for a Python caching library but can't find anything so far. I need a simple `dict`-like interface where I can set keys and their expiration and get them back cached. Sort of something like:

```
cache.get(myfunction, duration=300)
```

which will give me the item from the cache if it exists or call the function and store it if it doesn't or has expired. Does anyone know something like this?

Comment: i think you're missing `item` in your example.

Comment: Yes, this would probably need a key... And, 2.x.

Comment: within the same process or shared between processes?  threaded or not?

Comment: It should be thread-safe, sorry, I should have mentioned. I don't need to share between processes.

Comment: Try [DiskCache](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/): Apache2 licensed, 100% coverage, thread-safe, process-safe, multiple eviction policies and [fast (benchmarks)](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/cache-benchmarks.html).

Comment: Try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycache/0.1 and/or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycache/0.1

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Take a look at Beaker:

- [Home Page](http://beaker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Caching Documentation](http://beaker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/caching.html)
- [Good quick-start article about using Beaker with Django (but useful in any other apps too)](http://www.groovie.org/blog/advanced-caching-with-django-and-beaker)

Comment: Ah, I kept searching for this and all I found was a wiki that mentioned how to use it as an WSGI middleware. It looks like what I need, thank you.

Comment: See also [dogpile](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/dogpile.cache)- supposedly the new and improved beaker.

Answer (score 92):

From Python 3.2 you can use the decorator [@lru_cache](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) from the functools library.
It's a [Least Recently Used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Least_recently_used_(LRU)) cache, so there is no expiration time for the items in it, but as a fast hack it's very useful.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=256)
def f(x):
  return x*x

for x in range(20):
  print f(x)
for x in range(20):
  print f(x)
```

Comment: [cachetools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cachetools) offers an nice implementation of these and it's compatible python 2 and python 3.

Comment: big +1 for cachetools... seems pretty cool and has a couple more caching algorithms :)

Comment: This should never be suggested! Stay compatible.

Comment: @roboslone, two years (minus 4 days..) from your comment about not being thread safe, it may have changed. I have cachetools 2.0.0 and I see  in the code that it uses an RLock.
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cachetools/func.py

Comment: @Motty: The [documentation](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#cache-implementations) for cachetools 4.0.0.0 says this: "Please be aware that **all these classes are not thread-safe**. Access to a shared cache from multiple threads must be properly synchronized, e.g. by using one of the memoizing decorators with a suitable _lock_ object" (bold mine)

Answer (score 30):

You might also take a look at the [Memoize decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize).  You could probably get it to do what you want without too much modification.

Comment: That's clever. A few changes and the decorator could even expire after a set time.

Comment: You could definitely write a space-based limit to the cache in the decorator. That would be helpful if you wanted a function to, for example, generate the fibonacci sequence term by term. You want caching, but you only need the last two values - saving all of them is just space inefficient.

Answer (score 15):

**Joblib** https://joblib.readthedocs.io supports caching functions in the Memoize pattern. Mostly, the idea is to cache computationally expensive functions.

```
>>> from joblib import Memory
>>> mem = Memory(cachedir='/tmp/joblib')
>>> import numpy as np
>>> square = mem.cache(np.square)
>>> 
>>> a = np.vander(np.arange(3)).astype(np.float)
>>> b = square(a)                                   
________________________________________________________________________________
[Memory] Calling square...
square(array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  2.,  1.]]))
___________________________________________________________square - 0...s, 0.0min

>>> c = square(a)
```

You can also do fancy things like using the @memory.cache decorator on functions. The documentation is here: https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Memory.html

Comment: As a sidenote, joblib really shines when you're working with large NumPy arrays, since it has special methods to deal with them specifically.

Answer (score 15):

No one has mentioned shelve yet. https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html

It isn't memcached, but looks much simpler and might fit your need.

Comment: I wrote a thread- and multiprocess-safe wrapper for the standard shelve module (including a helper function for caching http requests) in case that is useful for anyone: https://github.com/cristoper/shelfcache

Answer (score 9):

I think [the python memcached API](http://www.tummy.com/Community/software/python-memcached/) is the prevalent tool, but I haven't used it myself and am not sure whether it supports the features you need.

Comment: That one's the industry standard, but all I want is a simple in-memory storage mechanism that can hold 100 keys or so, and memcached is a bit overkill. Thank you for the answer, though.

Answer (score 7):

```
import time

class CachedItem(object):
    def __init__(self, key, value, duration=60):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.duration = duration
        self.timeStamp = time.time()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<CachedItem {%s:%s} expires at: %s>' % (self.key, self.value, time.time() + self.duration)

class CachedDict(dict):

    def get(self, key, fn, duration):
        if key not in self \
            or self[key].timeStamp + self[key].duration < time.time():
                print 'adding new value'
                o = fn(key)
                self[key] = CachedItem(key, o, duration)
        else:
            print 'loading from cache'

        return self[key].value



if __name__ == '__main__':

    fn = lambda key: 'value of %s  is None' % key

    ci = CachedItem('a', 12)
    print ci 
    cd = CachedDict()
    print cd.get('a', fn, 5)
    time.sleep(2)
    print cd.get('a', fn, 6)
    print cd.get('b', fn, 6)
    time.sleep(2)
    print cd.get('a', fn, 7)
    print cd.get('b', fn, 7)
```

Comment: I did something like that, but you need locks for multithreading and a size parameter to avoid it growing infinitely. Then you need some function to sort the keys by accesses to discard the least-accessed ones, etc etc...

Comment: The __repr__ line is incorrect (should use the self.timeStamp). As well it's a poor implementation that needlessly does math for every get(). The expiry time should be calculated in the CachedItem init.

Comment: In fact, if you're only implementing the `get` method, this shouldn't be a dict subclass, it should be an object with an embedded dict.

Answer (score 6):

Try redis, it is one of the cleanest and easiest solutions for applications to share data in a atomic way or if you have got some web server platform. Its very easy to setup, you will need a python redis client http://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis

Comment: Should be mentioned, It is out of process, needs to be accessed using TCP.

Answer (score 6):

You can use my simple solution to the problem. It is really straightforward, nothing fancy:

```
class MemCache(dict):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        dict.__init__(self)
        self.__fn = fn

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item not in self:
            dict.__setitem__(self, item, self.__fn(item))
        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)

mc = MemCache(lambda x: x*x)

for x in xrange(10):
    print mc[x]

for x in xrange(10):
    print mc[x]
```

It indeed lacks expiration funcionality, but you can easily extend it with specifying a particular rule in MemCache c-tor.

Hope code is enough self-explanatory, but if not, just to mention, that cache is being passed a translation function as one of its c-tor params. It's used in turn to generate cached output regarding the input.

Hope it helps

Comment: +1 for suggesting something simple. Depending on the problem, it might just be the tool for the job. P.S. You don't need the `else` in `__getitem__` :)

Comment: Why would he not need to ```else``` in the ```__getitem__``` ? That's where he populates the dict...

Answer (score 4):

This [project](https://github.com/jneen/python-cache) aims to provide "Caching for humans"
(seems like it's fairly unknown though)

Some info from the project page:

#### Installation

pip install cache

#### Usage:

```
import pylibmc
from cache import Cache

backend = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1"])

cache = Cache(backend)

@cache("mykey")
def some_expensive_method():
    sleep(10)
    return 42

# writes 42 to the cache
some_expensive_method()

# reads 42 from the cache
some_expensive_method()

# re-calculates and writes 42 to the cache
some_expensive_method.refresh()

# get the cached value or throw an error
# (unless default= was passed to @cache(...))
some_expensive_method.cached()
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [gocept.cache](https://pypi.org/project/gocept.cache/) on pypi, manage timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Look at bda.cache http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bda.cache - uses ZCA and is tested with zope and bfg.

Answer (score 0):

ExpiringDict is another  option:

https://pypi.org/project/expiringdict/

Answer (score 0):

Besides all tools mentioned by others users earlier, you also can use [cacheout](https://pypi.org/project/cacheout/) pypi library.

It allows setting of cache timeout (TTL) for all keys or particular key and get value of particular key if needed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -8):

keyring is the best python caching library. You can use

```
keyring.set_password("service","jsonkey",json_res)

json_res= keyring.get_password("service","jsonkey")

json_res= keyring.core.delete_password("service","jsonkey")
```

Comment: That's a keyring library, not a caching library.

Comment: @StavrosKorokithakis Actually, i implemented caching of keys through keyring