# Adding a condition to check if project_item and branch is already parsed

Tags: python

there are ssh commands am running based on the project_item and branch..i dont want to run the ssh command on project_item and branch combo already ran,so I am  trying to add a condition to check if the project_item and branch combo is already parsed or not,any ideas on how to add it?

```
  for project_item in projects:
      branch = manifest_data(project_item)
      print "PROJECT_ITEM: " + project_item
      print "BRANCH: " + branch
      /*********condition to check if the project_item/branch combo is already parsed/***********
      mft = manifest_table(project_item,branch)
      if 'win32' in OS_Type and branch != 'PROJECT NOT ENBALED':
        #print OS_Type
        cmd = "\"\"%s\Git\\bin\sh.exe\" --login -c \"ssh -l user -p 29418 review-android.company.com gerrit query project:%s branch:%s --format=JSON status:open --commit-message --current-patch-set\"\" >> gerrit_output.txt" %(os.environ['ProgramFiles(x86)'], project_item,branch)
      elif 'linux' in OS_Type:
        #print OS_Type
        cmd = "ssh -l user -p 29418 review-android.company.com gerrit query project:%s branch:%s --format=JSON status:open --commit-message --current-patch-set\"\" >> gerrit_output.txt" %(project_item,branch)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parsed"? From your edit it seems like you mean "called". PS: there seems to be a typo: "ENBALED".

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to avoid running the same command twice, you simply have to remember the command and then check if you already ran it:

```
# Create a set to remember your executed commands. Sets are better than
# lists here, since you will repeatedly check if an item exists.
# See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity
executed_commands = set()

for project_item in projects:
    # Your posted code...

    identifier = hash((project_item, branch))
    # check if command has already been executed
    if identifier not in executed_commands:
        executed_commands.add(identifier)

        # Actually run cmd...
```

Comment: instead of checking the command..can we check if the project_item and branch combo is already parsed?

Comment: What do you mean by "parsed"? Is it what the `manifest_data` function does?

Comment: -i mean i dont want to run the ssh commands or any other logic for the same project_item and branch combo after the condition

Comment: @user3131197 Maybe you can write some pseudocode to help us understand?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but it seems like you're asking about how to check if a function has already been called once to only calculate something once?

The "memoize" pattern achieves this nicely. One version [can be found here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize).

The full code looks like this:

```
import collections
import functools

class memoized(object):
   '''Decorator. Caches a function's return value each time it is called.
   If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned
   (not reevaluated).
   '''
   def __init__(self, func):
      self.func = func
      self.cache = {}
   def __call__(self, *args):
      if not isinstance(args, collections.Hashable):
         # uncacheable. a list, for instance.
         # better to not cache than blow up.
         return self.func(*args)
      if args in self.cache:
         return self.cache[args]
      else:
         value = self.func(*args)
         self.cache[args] = value
         return value
   def __repr__(self):
      '''Return the function's docstring.'''
      return self.func.__doc__
   def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
      '''Support instance methods.'''
      return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)

@memoized
def fibonacci(n):
   "Return the nth fibonacci number."
   if n in (0, 1):
      return n
   return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

print fibonacci(12)
```

It simply caches the return value of a function. You might need some smarter caching, then you should check out a real cache, of course, but it looks like you're just optimizing so maybe this is a start.

Caching in Python has already been discussed here: [Is there a Python caching library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427255/is-there-a-python-caching-library)

Comment: -if you look at my code..there are ssh commands am running based on the project_item and branch..i dont want to run the ssh command on project_item and branch combo already ran,clear?

Comment: may we can put it an hash and then check the hash table if the project_item and combo is already parsed or not..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply store a hash of parsed objects in a list ?

```
parsed_list=[]
for project_item in projects:
    branch = manifest_data(project_item)
    item_hash = hash(branch+project_item)
    print "PROJECT_ITEM: " + project_item
    print "BRANCH: " + branch
    if item_hash not in parsed_list:
        parsed_list.append(item_hash)
        # more code
```

Comment: its not only branch.. the combo of project_item and branch should be in parset_list..we should check if the project_item and branch is already parsed..