# Persist a Python Object

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I am using Tweepy to make `stream` objects for using the streaming API and follow some users.

Now, users could be added by the users by calling a web-service. I want to disconnect the already running stream and restart it with the new users. I can't keep a reference to the `stream` object because users to follow can be added from multiple sources (web-services, background tasks etc).

I am thinking to persist the `stream` object in a database / file / whatever and then when a new user has to be added, a utility function could get the currently running `stream` from the database / file / whatever and call `disconnect` and start it again.

I am not able to persist the `stream` object (`pickle` does not work). How can I design such a scenario?

Comment: How about `caching` the `stream` object?

Comment: @Vaulstein how to `cache` the `stream` object. For me, `caching` means to store the object in a database / file / memcache or something else. To be able to do this, the object should be serializable but `pickle` is unable to serialize a module object. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Caching does not necessarily require the object to be stored in memory to be serializable.  You can check methods of caching all sorts of objects on [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427255/is-there-a-python-caching-library).