# How to autoload a little config data read frequently but nearly never being updated?

Tags: python, architecture, web

We have a little data which almost won't be updated but read frequently (site config and some selection items like states and counties information), I think if I can move it to application memory instead of any database, our I/O performance would get a big improvement.

But we have a lot of web servers, I cannot figure out a good solution how to notice all the servers to reload these data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely looking for a cache pattern:  [Is there a Python caching library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427255/is-there-a-python-caching-library) You just need to ask how stale you can afford to be.  If it was looking this up on every request, even a short-lived cache can massively improve performance.  It's likely though that this information can live for minutes or hours without too much risk of being "stale".

If you can't live with a stale cache, I've implemented solutions that have a single database call, which keeps track of the last updated date for *any* of the cached data.  This at least reduces the cache lookups to a single database call.

Be aware though, as soon as you are sharing updateable information, you have to deal with multi-threaded updates of shared state.  Make sure you understand the implications of this.  Hopefully your caching library handles this gracefully.